# How to create child router-outlet in a lazy loaded feature module?

Tags: angular

So, I have an Angular 8 application which consists of the following project structure:

[image: project structure]

`app-routing.module.ts` contains the primary routes to the lazy loaded modules `auth` and `dashboard`. `app.component` contains the `router-outlet` by which the primary routing takes place. This is working fine.

However, what I want is to have a `dashboard.page` which will contain the navbar,sidebar, etc. components and another `router-outlet` which will change components based on the secondary route. Eg., `/dashboard` should take me to the `dashboard.page` because of the primary router in `app.component`. `/dashboard/new` should take me to the `dashboard.page` and within it, the child router-outlet should have `temp.screen` on it, which will change depending on what I click on the sidebar.

So far, this does not work when I lazy load the modules. If I were to eager load the page components themselves, then this entire flow works perfectly. Is there someway to get this to work even in a lazy loaded format?

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { DashboardPage } from "./page/dashboard.page";
import { TempTwoScreen } from "./screens/temp-two/temp-two.screen";
import { TempScreen } from './screens/temp/temp.screen';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: DashboardPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                component: TempScreen,
                outlet: "dboard",
            },
            {
                path: "new",
                component: TempTwoScreen,
                outlet: "dboard",
            },
        ],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        loadChildren: () => import("./modules/auth/auth.module").then((m) => m.AuthModule),
    },
    {
        path: "dashboard",
        loadChildren: () => import("./modules/dashboard/dashboard.module").then((m) => m.DashboardModule),
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { enableTracing: true, relativeLinkResolution: "corrected" })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { IndexScreen } from "./screens/index/index.screen";
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from "./dashboard-routing.module";
import { DashboardPage } from "./page/dashboard.page";
import { TempScreen } from "./screens/temp/temp.screen";
import { TempTwoScreen } from "./screens/temp-two/temp-two.screen";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        DashboardPage,

        TempTwoScreen,
        TempScreen,
        IndexScreen,
    ],
    imports: [CommonModule, DashboardRoutingModule, FormsModule],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the following files: app-routing.module.ts, dashboard.module.ts, and dashboard-routing.module.ts?

Comment: @anymeshsingh added.

Comment: your code is fine, you just need to add another 'router-outlet' inside dashboard.component.html that will load all the subroutes inside dashboard like '/dashboard/temp' or '/dashboard/temp2'. The '/temp' and '/temp2' after '/dashboard' will load the temp component and temp2 component inside router-outlet that is present inside dashboard compomnet.

Comment: So i've added another router-outlet in my dashboard.page.html that is supposed to load subroutes, but that works only for the first route, on the empty route. Any other links I go to via a routerlink breaks the entire code, saying it can't find the route.

Comment: You mean for '/dashboard' you go to the TempScreen inside of Dashboard but for path '/dashboard/new' you are not going to the TempTwoScreen. You can try going to the same route i.e. '/dashboard/new' directly from the URL and if it works that means you are giving an incorrect path for 'routerLink'. Try giving something like routerLink="/dashboard/new". But it does not work however then let me know I will share code from one of the projects to show you how it is working for me.

Comment: I tried going on the same route via the url, and it still does not work. Can you share code for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you will notice differences in my file below is in **app-routing.module.ts** file for dashboard module I am not giving any path. I am giving the **/dashboard** path in the **dashboard-routing.module.ts** (this is because for the other sub-links I didn't want **/dashboard** to be prefixed in the URL) but I tested your way also and it was working for me.

Secondly, I am lazy loading sub-modules which does not make any difference.

Thirdly I am using an Overview component which is loaded on **/dashboard** path inside the **dashboard.component.html**'s **router-outlet**

The code below is the working code I am currently using in an Angular 8.2 project.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { AuthGuard } from "./guards/auth.guard";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: "/login" },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./dashboard/dashboard.module").then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: "**",
    redirectTo: ""
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      enableTracing: true,
      relativeLinkResolution: "corrected"
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**dashboard-routing.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard.component";
import { OverviewComponent } from "./overview/overview.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "dashboard",
        component: OverviewComponent
      },
      {
        path: "profile",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./profile/profile.module").then(m => m.ProfileModule)
      },
      {
        path: "roles",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./roles/roles.module").then(m => m.RolesModule)
      },
      {
        path: "users",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./users/users.module").then(m => m.UsersModule)
      },
      {
        path: "products",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./products/products.module").then(m => m.ProductsModule)
      },
      {
        path: "orders",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./orders/orders.module").then(m => m.OrdersModule)
      },
      {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule {}
```

In my **dashboard.component.html** I am using **routerLink** as

```html
...
<li *ngIf="role.Orders.Read" nz-menu-item nzMatchRouter routerLink="/orders" style="outline: none !important">
  <i nz-icon nzType="shopping-cart"></i>
  <span><a class="text-white">ORDERS</a></span>
</li>
...
```